The data changed while importing JSON into Redshift using Super
I inserted the JSON:
{key1:xxx, key2:xxx, ..., key3:1.0000000123456789, ..., keyn:xxx}
into a Super type column in Redshift, and it resulted in the following on Redshift:
{key1:xxx, key2:xxx, ..., key3:1.0000000123456787, ..., keyn:xxx}.
The value of key3 changed from 9 at the end to 7
Why did such a error occur?
I suspect that the error occurred due to the JSON data being converted into binary and then restored, possibly involving truncation of the binary data. If there are any facts regarding this, I would appreciate your help.

I believe JSON only has INT and FLOAT as number types and you are likely running into the max precision of a FLOAT.  You can update the SUPER after it is defined using a DOUBLE to regain the precision.
